# Spark Change Column type failed

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
root
 |-- dt: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- AverageTemperature: double (nullable = true)
 |-- AverageTemperatureUncertainty: double (nullable = true)
 |-- City: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Country: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Latitude: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Longitude: string (nullable = true)
```

I have the above Data Schema from Spark. I am trying to change the type timestamp in dt to string

```
temperature_df.withColumn("dt",col("dt").cast(StringType()))
```

This is what I did, and I got the following error :

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Can someone explain to me why I got this error?

Comment: In which line you have that error, can you share the code causing the problem because I see no possible reason of that error based on the line that you shared and the schema, otherwise do you have any object called col in your code ?

Comment: ```temperature_df.withColumn("dt",col("dt").cast(StringType()))``` This is the line. No I don't have any object called col.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work (make sure to import StringType from `pyspark.sql.types`:

```
temperature_df.withColumn("dt",temperature_df.dt.cast(StringType()))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f 
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
temperature_df.withColumn("dt",f.col("dt").cast(StringType()))
```